# Update from ADB option under recovery menu

Tags: updates, adb

How does one typically use the "Update from ADB" option in the Recovery menu? Do I have to connect the phone via a usb cable to my laptop & provide the necessary update files?

Where on the laptop do I keep the update files & where will I download these files from?

In case my phone model helps it is a Moto G 1st edition XT1033.

Answer (score 3):

IDK which Recovery (stock/custom) your device is running because in my device CWM 6.0 for Android 4.2.1 shows "Install zip from sideload" option. Anyhow, I've [verified](https://gist.github.com/eyecatchup/ec0a852428c19705380e) that both options points to same thing i.e. sideloading from PC.

This option will allow you to push a `.zip` file into the device accompanied by an automated installation of it. For a custom recovery this file can be any app, binary or system update. For a Stock recovery, you'll have to see what it allows to push. (I'm assuming you can only push signed system updates from them.)

The usage is simple. Choose the option in recovery which will show some output like:

> Send the package to the device with `adb sideload <filename>`...

Your device (as obvious) has to be connected into PC with ADB drivers installed. Issue the command `adb sideload filename.zip` where filename.zip is the `.zip` file you want to sideload. It will show some [processing](http://www.talkandroid.com/guides/beginner/how-to-install-the-lollipop-ota-on-your-nexus-device-download-links-included/) and eventually will install.

Comment: @FirelordThanks for the tips! Is there a way to tell which Recovery I am running? I am sure I have not added / changed the recovery so my Recovery is whatever Motorola decided to ship with the phone.  If it helps the screen says "Android system recovery <3e> KXB21.14-L1.40"

Comment: If you haven't changed the recovery, then it's a stock recovery. Don't bother to search or note down the version number of it. It won't help you to get anywhere. :) Also, some popular custom recoveries are CWM,TWRP and Philz touch. If you happen to have any of them then you'll be able to see their name easily.

Comment: I'm thinking of using the file posted on [this site](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/general/index-moto-g-falcon-factory-firmware-t3110795) listed as **"Moto G (Falcon) Factory Firmware Images"** My phone is an XT1033 and purchased in India so the version listed as _"Retail Asia - ASIARETAIL_XT1033_5.0.2_LXB22.46-28_cid7"_ seems my closest bet. Just thought I'd post to see if I am doing anything obviously stupid?

Comment: One puzzling part is that that file is  an xml.zip. Will that work to install the way you described or do I need anything different for that format?

Comment: @curious_cat The link that you mentioned has a flashing guide which links to [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2542219). It is mentioned that if you've download a `.xml.zip` file then you'll have to use `mfastboot` to do the flashing.

Comment: Yes, I saw that link. I just wanted to avoid messing with mfastboot if at all possible. I guess not. adb seemed safer. The mfastboot instructions are real low level and numerous. Lot more chance to brick my phone IMO. Guess I must take the risk.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23967/discussion-between-firelord-and-curious-cat).