# How to flash stock ROM over ADB sideload

Tags: rom-flashing, unbricking

After successfully rooting my phone, I mistakenly soft-bricked my phone by modifying the `build.prop` file. Some research tells me that the only way to repair it was to flash the **stock ROM**.

I have already downloaded the stock ROM. All I need to do is flash it.

I tried flashing the ROM using **SP Flash Tool**, as my phone uses a **Mediatek processor**. However, it doesn't work.

So now I thought of flashing over **ADB sideload**. So could you please tell me how is that supposed to be done?

In the command `adb sideload <filename>` whether the `<filename>` has to contain the zipped version of the stock ROM or something else.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) What didn't work with SP Flash Tool which is the champion in flashing MTK phones? 2) Which device have you got, and which Android version did you brick? 3) Can you share the link or the tutorial from where you obtained the stock ROM? 4) Do you have a custom Recovery installed? 5) See this for [ADB sideload](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/109923/96277).

Comment: 1. The SP flash tool doesn't do anything when I connect my phone and click on "Download". 2. It's a Karbonn A52+ running 4.2.2 Jelly Bean. 3. I downloaded it from http://www.needrom.com/download/karbonn-a52-2 4. No, it's running the stock recovery.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the original `build.prop`? Can you still boot into... oh, stock-recovery. Strike that part. Can you flash a custom recovery (e.g. CWM/TWRP) to your device, and would that be an option?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the backup of the original build.prop, but I remember what I had edited.. I had just added a line to the top.. And unfortunately I don't have much idea about flashing custom ROMS..

Comment: The ROM you downloaded is a scatter based ROM meant to be flashed using SP Flash Tools (the instructions at that needrom page are half-baked)  and I don't think `adb sideload` would help with that ROM (that just an opinion because I never tried flashing a scatter based ROM using `adb sideload`) // There is an alternative [here](http://androidxda.com/flash-pac-stock-rom-android-smartphone).

Comment: And please use @ followed by the name of the person to whom you want to convey your point, otherwise, no body will come to know what you wrote. (e.g. @Izzy for your last comment).

Comment: Yupp, @Firelord is right: without his comment I'd get no note (only OP always receives notifies). To get an idea, you could start with our [clockworkmod-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/clockworkmod-recovery/info). It would allow you to run ADB while in recovery, mount `/system`, and revert your changes. // Hint for "next time": Most stuff you can try out using `adb shell` and the `setprop` command. If that crashes your device, a simple reboot fixes it :)

Comment: @Izzy I tried adb shell command but it shows error:closed..

Comment: @Firelord could you please hunt me a .pac ROM for my device, as I'm unable to do so..

Comment: @Firelord thanks for the link.. It shows me a link to Google Drive, i.e., https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0Bx-UuraN82UeQWNPR05SSmUwWVE
So after decompressing it would it give me a .pac file?

Comment: @TanmayVij Sure, stock-recoveries usually do *not* have an ADB daemon running. custom recoveries like CWM/TWRP do, that was what I was pointing to. So you'd first need to get a custom recovery installed, then boot into that, and *then* you can run `adb shell`. That's not only a restriction of MTK devices, by the way ;)

Comment: FINALLY MY DEVICE IS RUNNING FINE :) :) The SP Flash tool worked like heaven for me :) The problem was I didn't have an SD Card in my phone while using it. After inserting the card it worked fine for me :) :)

Comment: As I said the very first time, it is the champion. Now that the problem has been solved, could you please write an answer to your question so that others can benefit from it? Please be detailed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally was able to solve this problem, as *[Firelord](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/96277/firelord)* said, adb sideload wasn't able to help in the case of this ROM. And SP Flash tool turns out to be the best for MediaTek devices.

Most of the ROMs (Stock or Custom) are available on http://www.needrom.com, so I would recommend it to others for downloading ROMS. However, the website requires signing up in order to download ROMs.

SP Flash Tool, in order to work, needs the following things:

- A formatted SD Card in your Mobile Device
- Battery to be re-inserted after removing (within 10-15 seconds)
- Media Tek VCOM drivers to be installed in your PC. (Link: https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B9srKhKuVIMnalFkV3EzWjVXdUE)
- A scatter-based ROM for your device.

> **Note:** SP Flash tool needs to be Run as Administrator while using it.

A factory data reset from the Recovery mode is advisable after successful flashing.